# search is not working , in yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview

I installed yii2 export menu.it working fine but search is not working properly.i cant understand whats going wrong? please help to fix it...
here is code-

```
<?php
        $gridColumns = [
        [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
        ],
        'name',
        'company_mail',    
        'created',
         'modified',
        'modified_by_id',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'urlCreator'=>function(){return '#';}],

    ]; ?>

<?php
echo ExportMenu::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK,
  ]); 

?>
<?php 
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `companiesController.php`

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

this line was commented by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add to following function to your search model

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = YourModel::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [

                ]
            ],
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }


        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'company_mail', $this->company_mail])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modified', $this->modified])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'created', $this->created])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modified_by_id', $this->modified_by_id]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: thanks... but it doesnt work ...this code is already present in my project.. .... please suggest anything else